# Heiken Ashi candles plotted on graph Binance

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, binance

So I'm trying to plot Heiken Ashi candles, and then I want to plot them on graph.

My code so far:

```
def heikin_ashi():
    historical_data = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=SYMBOL, interval=TIME_PERIOD, start_str="15 days ago UTC", klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.FUTURES)
    hist_df = pd.DataFrame(historical_data)
    hist_df.columns = ['Open Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close Time', 'Quote Asset Volume',
                       'Number of Trades', 'TB Base Volume', 'TB Quote Volume', 'Ignore']

    hist_df['Open Time'] = pd.to_datetime(hist_df['Open Time']/1000, unit='s')
    hist_df['Close Time'] = pd.to_datetime(hist_df['Close Time']/1000, unit='s')

    df_HA = hist_df
    df_HA['Close'] = (hist_df['Open'] + hist_df['High'] + hist_df['Low'] + hist_df['Close']) / 4

    # idx = df_HA.index.name
    # df_HA.reset_index(inplace=True)

    for i in range(0, len(hist_df)):
        if i == 0:
            df_HA['Open'][i] = ((hist_df['Open'][i] + hist_df['Close'][i]) / 2)
        else:
            df_HA['Open'][i] = ((hist_df['Open'][i - 1] + hist_df['Close'][i - 1]) / 2)

    # if idx:
    # df_HA.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

    df_HA['High'] = hist_df[['Open', 'Close', 'High']].max(axis=1)
    df_HA['Low'] = hist_df[['Open', 'Close', 'Low']].min(axis=1)

    print(df_HA)
```

Error:

```
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Also I came across this:

```
import pandas as pd

def heikin_ashi(df):
    heikin_ashi_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.values, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
    
    heikin_ashi_df['close'] = (df['open'] + df['high'] + df['low'] + df['close']) / 4
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[0, 0] = df['open'].iloc[0]
        else:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[i, 0] = (heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 0] + heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 3]) / 2
        
    heikin_ashi_df['high'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['high']).max(axis=1)
    
    heikin_ashi_df['low'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['low']).min(axis=1)
    
    return heikin_ashi_df
```

How do I use the above code with my data? I'm a novice, so I'm confused. I'd appreciate it if someone could provide me with a proper way to do this.

Link to the source: https://github.com/emreturan/heikin-ashi/blob/master/heikin_ashi.py

I need to plot this on a graph too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the 'heikin_ashi' code to answer the example of using mplfinance, a popular finance library, for the graph. There are many other libraries available for visualizing investments, so we will use this as a basic form for data acquisition and visualization. A sample of mplfinance can be found [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/tree/master/examples) for reference.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-07-01", end="2022-01-01", progress=False)
data.columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'adj close', 'volume']

def heikin_ashi(df):
    heikin_ashi_df = df.copy()
    #heikin_ashi_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.values, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
    heikin_ashi_df['close'] = (df['open'] + df['high'] + df['low'] + df['close']) / 4
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[0, 0] = df['open'].iloc[0]
        else:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[i, 0] = (heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 0] + heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 3]) / 2
        
    heikin_ashi_df['high'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['high']).max(axis=1)
    
    heikin_ashi_df['low'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['low']).min(axis=1)
    
    return heikin_ashi_df

df_ha = heikin_ashi(data)
# mpf plotting
mpf.plot(df_ha, type='candle', figratio=(8,4), title='APPL', style='yahoo')
```

[image]

Comment: For the data sources and stocks, I used Yahoo Finance and APPL for the sample. If there are other libraries you would like to use, please comment. We may be able to help you depending on the content.